# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

Tags: python, python-3.x

через terminal устанавливаю модуль

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install pyperclip
```

В терминале выводится:

```
“Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.8.1)”
```

Если набрать команду:

```
$ pydoc modules
```

То в списке его нет.

Если в коде набрать – “import pyperclip”, то при запуске выводится следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maksimsmirnov/Documents/Python/Учебные проекты/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Сам код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
             'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01iflMLZF3sdt',
             'luggage': '12345'}
import sys 
import pyperclip
if len(sys.ardv) < 2:
    print('Испольвание: python pw.py [имя учетной записи] – копирование пароля учетной записи')
    sys.exit()
account = sys.argv[1]

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Пароль для ' + account + 'скопирован в буфер.')
else:
    print('Учетная запись' + account + 'отсутствует в списке')
```

Не пойму как это исправить.

Comment: Каким **IDE** вы пользуетесь? Используете ли вы `virtualenv`?

Comment: IDE – PyCharm. virtualenv не использую.